# Python dictionary subset

Tags: python, dictionary, subset

I'm new to python and I have to extract subdict from dict. I have a dictionary like this

```
{'stat': u'AS', 'vyska': 3.72, 'stanice': u'AQW00061705', 'mesic': 1, 'teplotaC': 26.88}
```

I want python to print `value of 'stat' and 'teplotaC'` but only if the `'mesic' in (6,7,8)`. So in the example above, the python will return nothing, but if the dictionary looks like this:

```
{'stat': u'AS', 'vyska': 3.72, 'stanice': u'AQW00061705', 'mesic': 8, 'teplotaC': 26.88}
```

it will retrun `AS 26.88` Any advice?

I know some basics how to work with dicts in python, like how to access some value by the key etc. But my dict is much more bigger than this example and I have like 5000 dicts and I have to find out in each one of them, if `"mesic" in (6,7,8)` and if so, I have to return the `"stat" and "teplotaC"`. So I need some function where I enter the dict and when the condition for `"mesic"` is `True` then it will return the `stat` and `teplotaC`.

Comment: Advice: read some books on Python. Working with dicts is very basic knowledge.

Comment: I know some basics so I will add information about my basic knowledge to question. 
But my dict is much more bigger than this example and I have like 5000 dicts and I have to find out in each one of them, if "mesic" in (6,7,8) and if so, I have to return the "stat" and "teplotaC" . So I need some function where I enter the dict and when the condition for "mesic" is True then it will return the stat and teplotaC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***: for multiple dictionaries

Iterate over your dictionaries and for every one of them, check if the value of 'mesic' is in [6,7,8] and if so, get the corresponding dictionary values:

```
d1 = {'stat': u'AS', 'vyska': 3.72, 'stanice': u'AQW00061705', 'mesic': 8, 'teplotaC': 26.88}
d2 = {'stat': u'AS', 'vyska': 3.72, 'stanice': u'AQW00061705', 'mesic': 1, 'teplotaC': 26.88}
list_of_dicts = [d1, d2]

for dic in list_of_dicts:
    if dic['mesic'] in [6,7,8]:
        print(dic['stat'], dic['teplotaC'])
```

Comment: Oh is it really that simple?! I feel stupid... So thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

**[Python Dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary)**

```
d = {'stat': u'AS', 'vyska': 3.72, 'stanice': u'AQW00061705', 'mesic': 1, 'teplotaC': 26.88}
print d["stat"]
print d['teplotaC']
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this command so I edit my question little bit to be more specific.